# How to read data from HDFS with Flink in python

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-flink, flink-sql, pyflink

I want to read data from HDFS with Flink in python
I found it possible with Java or Scala :
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/dataset/formats/hadoop/

Indeed, Flink HDFS connector provides a Sink that writes partitioned files to any filesystem supported by Hadoop FileSystem.

I know I need to use InputFormat to try and specify that, but I cannot find a good guide to this in Python.
there is no support to do that in python (pyFlink)

Please any help will be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with myself,
just need to configure class_path of hadoop and create flink sql table
) WITH (
'connector' = 'filesystem',
'path' = 'hdfs://namenode:9000/directory/',
'format' = 'json'
)